# C# : why explicit conversion from Int to <Nullable> int?

Tags: c#, .net

```
  int a = 1;
  int? b = a; 
  Console.WriteLine(b);
```

The above snippet is fine and will convert `int` directly to `int?`, no explicit conversion is required

but

```
List<int> temp = new List<int>{1};      
int? valueVariable = temp!=null && temp.Count>0 ? temp[0] : null ;
Console.WriteLine(valueVariable);
```

will have compile time error.

to fix this We need to cast to `int?`

```
// Working Snippet with int? casting
int? valueVariable = temp!=null && temp.Count > 0 ? (int?) temp[0] : null ;
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/0x7ckL

**Why we needed casting here,although the same was working for first example?**

Comment: Because in the first case your are moving primitive type to reference type. In the seconth case your are doing the inverse. You cannot convert a reference type directly to your requested primitive value.

Comment: There is no reference type involved here. `null` doesn't have a type and is a fine default value for a nullable value type, without involving reference types.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that ternary operator must use the SAME type in both branches. So true and false return values must be either int? or int. Cannot use two different types.

Comment: This is not correct. The two branches doesn't have to have the same type but there has to be an explicit conversion available in either direction in the case where they're not. `null` doesn't have a specific type and as such there is no such conversion available. This is why the compiler refuses to compile it. It is fine to use `? intVal : nullableIntVal` which doesn't have the same types.

Comment: Thanks for more specific answer!